# Solve differential eq. $f(x) -x=2xf(x)(xf(x))'$ for $f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^n a_i a_{n-i}$ with $a_0=0,a_1=1$.

Let $f(x):=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i$. Then, this recurrence formula can be rewritten as 
$$\int (f(x) -x)dx=(f(x))^2 x^2$$
$$\Rightarrow f(x) -x=2xf(x)(xf(x))'.$$
Then, I tried to separete variable $x,f(x)$ to left and right-hand side, but it fails. How to solve this differential equation?

Comment: This is a Chini equation and I doubt that there is a closed form solution

Comment: Note usre if it leads anywhere but looks simpler if we make the substitution $y = xf(x)$ and the ODE becomes
$$
\frac{y}{x} - x = 2yy' \iff y - 2xyy' = x^2 \iff 2y' = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{y}
$$

Comment: I check $a(n)n!$ numerically, $[a_00!,a_11!,\ldots,]=[0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 16, 0, 272, 0, 7936, 0, 353792,\ldots]$. This corresponds to the coefficient of $\tan(x)$.

Comment: But This doesn't seems to satisfy the differential equation ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula, $\int (f(x)-x)dx = (f(x))^2x^2$ is wrong.
It should be
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)-1=(f(x))^2.$$
From $\frac{d}{dx}\tan(x)-1=\tan^2(x)$ and $\tan(0)=0,\frac{d}{dx}\tan(0)=1$, we get $f(x)=\tan(x)$.